# How to see the whole code without scrolling to the right (VS Code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code. My monitor is kinda small in width so I cannot see the whole code especially with the long lines. It's so annoying to scroll left to right or vice versa every single time. I cannot focus on coding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, hit the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to enable wrapping of the code without ruining the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In Macbook press `Option` + `Z` to enable wrapping of the code without ruining the line numbers.